Netflix slider card hover owlcarousel tailwind
I want to recreate the netflix slider using tailwind and owlcarousel. It's almost done as I want but I'm facing a problem when I hover the card I apply a scaling up to the card to display details but I actually can't click on them.
Does anyone can help me with this ? here is the fiddle
HTML structure
<section class="mx-auto w-screen relative flex flex-col gap-4 px-5 mb-16">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item group transition-all sm:hover:absolute sm:hover:scale-125 border border-red-600">
            <div href="#" class="card bg-neutral-900 rounded-md cursor-pointer overflow-hidden">
                <div>
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKSRTtOrtjLaagEC2gTK6VsPq4NEFk_72hhg&s"
                        alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="hidden group-hover:flex bg-white p-1.5 flex-col h-fit w-full">
                    <div class="flex gap-3 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                        <span class="">
                            MOVIE TITLE
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <a href="" class="text-red-600 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                        try to click me you can't
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item group transition-all sm:hover:absolute sm:hover:scale-125 border border-red-600 overflow-hidden">
            <div href="#" class="card bg-neutral-900 rounded-md cursor-pointer overflow-hidden">
                <div>
                    <img src="https://occ-0-6613-7435.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v6/Qs00mKCpRvrkl3HZAN5KwEL1kpE/AAAABQquP3MObc4Xmx8fS1E0EtFypAJFcNs8U73s6OHL2GjPOuIRbKkknfytMjCRkky6eDIe_8LHwBndef1-gQiN3IMX5NEqFRShrIi9MKSOMGvoTalZ2GRya1eswfUOXrTJ6Nnflg.webp?r=bb3"
                        alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="hidden group-hover:flex bg-white p-1.5 flex-col h-fit w-full">
                    <div class="flex gap-3 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                        <span class="">
                            MOVIE TITLE
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <a href="" class="text-red-600 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                        try to click me you can't
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item group transition-all sm:hover:absolute sm:hover:scale-125 border border-red-600">
            <div href="#" class="card bg-neutral-900 rounded-md cursor-pointer overflow-hidden">
                <div>
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKSRTtOrtjLaagEC2gTK6VsPq4NEFk_72hhg&s"
                        alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="hidden group-hover:flex bg-white p-1.5 flex-col h-fit w-full">
                    <div class="flex gap-3 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                        <span class="">
                            MOVIE TITLE
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <a href="" class="text-red-600 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                        try to click me you can't
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item group transition-all sm:hover:absolute sm:hover:scale-125 border border-red-600">
            <div href="#" class="card bg-neutral-900 rounded-md cursor-pointer overflow-hidden">
                <div>
                    <img src="https://placecats.com/340/192" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="hidden group-hover:flex bg-white p-1.5 flex-col h-fit w-full">
                    <div class="flex gap-3 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                        <span class="">
                            MOVIE TITLE
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <a href="" class="text-red-600 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                        try to click me you can't
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item group transition-all sm:hover:absolute sm:hover:scale-125 border border-red-600">
            <div href="#" class="card bg-neutral-900 rounded-md cursor-pointer overflow-hidden">
                <div>
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKSRTtOrtjLaagEC2gTK6VsPq4NEFk_72hhg&s"
                        alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="hidden group-hover:flex bg-white p-1.5 flex-col h-fit w-full">
                    <div class="flex gap-3 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                        <span class="">
                            MOVIE TITLE
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <a href="" class="text-red-600 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                        try to click me you can't
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item group transition-all sm:hover:absolute sm:hover:scale-125 border border-red-600">
            <div href="#" class="card bg-neutral-900 rounded-md cursor-pointer overflow-hidden">
                <div>
                    <img src="https://occ-0-6613-7435.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v6/Qs00mKCpRvrkl3HZAN5KwEL1kpE/AAAABQquP3MObc4Xmx8fS1E0EtFypAJFcNs8U73s6OHL2GjPOuIRbKkknfytMjCRkky6eDIe_8LHwBndef1-gQiN3IMX5NEqFRShrIi9MKSOMGvoTalZ2GRya1eswfUOXrTJ6Nnflg.webp?r=bb3"
                        alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="hidden group-hover:flex bg-white p-1.5 flex-col h-fit w-full">
                    <div class="flex gap-3 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                        <span class="">
                            MOVIE TITLE
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <a href="" class="text-red-600 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                        try to click me you can't
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item group transition-all sm:hover:absolute sm:hover:scale-125 border border-red-600">
            <div href="#" class="card bg-neutral-900 rounded-md cursor-pointer overflow-hidden">
                <div>
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKSRTtOrtjLaagEC2gTK6VsPq4NEFk_72hhg&s"
                        alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="hidden group-hover:flex bg-white p-1.5 flex-col h-fit w-full">
                    <div class="flex gap-3 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                        <span class="">
                            MOVIE TITLE
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <a href="" class="text-red-600 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                        try to click me you can't
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

Javascript
const addHoverClasses = (event) => {
  const owlitemHovered = event.currentTarget
  owlitemHovered.classList.add("!z-10")
  owlitemHovered.classList.remove("!z-0")
}

const removeHoverClasses = (event) => {
  const owlitemHovered = event.currentTarget
  owlitemHovered.classList.remove("!z-10")
  owlitemHovered.classList.add("!z-0")
}

const getOwlcarouselResponsiveMaxItems = (event) => {
  const owlInstance = event.relatedTarget
  const currentBreakpoint = owlInstance._breakpoint
  const breakpoints = owlInstance.options.responsive

  return breakpoints[currentBreakpoint].items
}

const applyTransformOrigin = (event) => {
  const owlCarousel = event.target
  const owlItems = owlCarousel.querySelectorAll(".owl-item")
  let owlItemActiveCounter = 1
  owlItems.forEach((owlItem, index) => {
    owlItem.classList.add("!z-0")
    owlItem.firstChild.classList.remove(
      "origin-[left_center]",
      "origin-[right_center]",
      "origin-center",
    )
    if (owlItem?.classList.contains("active")) {
      if (owlItemActiveCounter === 1) {
        owlItem.firstChild.classList.add("origin-[left_center]")
      } else if (
        owlItemActiveCounter === getOwlcarouselResponsiveMaxItems(event)
      ) {
        owlItem.firstChild.classList.add("origin-[right_center]")
      } else {
        owlItem.firstChild.classList.add("origin-center")
      }
      owlItemActiveCounter++
    }
  })
}

const applyOwlStyles = (event) => {
  const owlCarousel = event.target
  const owlItems = owlCarousel.querySelectorAll(".owl-item")

  owlCarousel.classList.add("relative")
  owlCarousel
    .querySelector(".owl-stage-outer")
    ?.classList.add("!overflow-visible", "!overflow-x-clip")

  owlItems.forEach((owlItem, index) => {
    owlItem.addEventListener("mouseover", addHoverClasses, false)
    owlItem.addEventListener("mouseout", removeHoverClasses, false)
  })

  const owldotsContainer = owlCarousel.querySelector(".owl-dots")
  owldotsContainer?.classList.add(
    "absolute",
    "!-top-4",
    "right-0",
    "-translate-y-full",
    "!flex",
    "!gap-2",
    "!items-center",
  )

  const owldots = owldotsContainer?.querySelectorAll(".owl-dot") ?? []
  owldots.forEach((olwDot) => {
    const span = olwDot.querySelector("span")
    span.classList.add("!m-0", "!rounded-none", "!w-4", "!h-1")
    span.classList.remove("!bg-primary-600")
    if (olwDot.classList.contains("active")) {
      span.classList.add("!bg-primary-600")
    }
  })

  const owlNav = owlCarousel?.querySelector(".owl-nav")
  owlNav?.classList.add("!m-0", "!top-0", "!bottom-0", "!w-full")

  const owlPrev = owlNav?.querySelector(".owl-prev")
  const owlNext = owlNav?.querySelector(".owl-next")

  owlPrev?.classList.add(
    "!absolute",
    "!h-full",
    "!m-0",
    "!bg-black",
    "!bg-opacity-60",
    "!text-white",
    "!text-6xl",
    "!font-opensans",
    "!left-0",
    "!w-[40px]",
    "!rounded-none",
    "!rounded-r-md",
    "-translate-y-full",
  )
  owlNext?.classList.add(
    "!absolute",
    "!h-full",
    "!m-0",
    "!bg-black",
    "!bg-opacity-60",
    "!text-white",
    "!text-6xl",
    "!font-opensans",
    "!right-0",
    "!w-[40px]",
    "!rounded-none",
    "!rounded-l-md",
    "-translate-y-full",
  )

  owlPrev?.querySelector("span").classList.add("align-super")
  owlNext?.querySelector("span").classList.add("align-super")
}

jQuery(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  stagePadding: 50,
  nav: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1,
    },
    600: {
      items: 3,
    },
    1000: {
      items: 5,
    },
  },
  onInitialized: (event) => {
    applyOwlStyles(event)
    applyTransformOrigin(event)
  },
  onTranslated: (event) => {
    applyTransformOrigin(event)
  },
  onResized: (event) => {
    applyOwlStyles(event)
    applyTransformOrigin(event)
  },
})


Thanks for the warning, but this is more about css than owlcarousel itself.

The problem is that .owl-stage:after takes the size of .owl-item.
When you use scale, the size recognized by JavaScript doesn’t change, and the mouseout event on .owl-carousel is triggered when you leave the actual carousel and not the scaled item.
To fix this, I created a parent div called .owl-carousel-container that detects the size of the carousel and maintains the same size. Inside this div, I allow .owl-stage:after to be as large as it wants. This prevents the undesired mouseout behavior.
To ensure the .owl-carousel-container div stays synchronized in size, I use the Owl Carousel events and also a repetition with setTimeout to handle any delays that might cause issues.
I added multiple repetitions, but you can test and see if it’s possible to reduce the number.
Finally, I also had to synchronize the size of the .owl-prev and .owl-next buttons. For this, I created a global variable to ensure they are all updated together.


const originalWarn = console.warn;
  console.warn = (msg, ...args) => {
    if (!msg.includes('Tailwind')) {
      originalWarn(msg, ...args);
    }
};

const htmlElement = document.documentElement,
  head = document.querySelector("head")

// only for stackoverflow works!
const scriptTailwind = document.createElement("script")
scriptTailwind.src = "https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/"
head.append(scriptTailwind)

scriptTailwind.onload = () => {
  const addHoverClasses = (event) => {
    const owlitemHovered = event.currentTarget
    owlitemHovered.classList.add("!z-10")
    owlitemHovered.classList.remove("!z-0")
  }

  const removeHoverClasses = (event) => {
    const owlitemHovered = event.currentTarget
    owlitemHovered.classList.remove("!z-10")
    owlitemHovered.classList.add("!z-0")
  }

  const getOwlcarouselResponsiveMaxItems = (event) => {
    const owlInstance = event.relatedTarget
    const currentBreakpoint = owlInstance._breakpoint
    const breakpoints = owlInstance.options.responsive

    return breakpoints[currentBreakpoint].items
  }

  const applyTransformOrigin = (event) => {
    const owlCarousel = event.target
    const owlItems = owlCarousel.querySelectorAll(".owl-item")
    let owlItemActiveCounter = 1
    owlItems.forEach((owlItem, index) => {
      owlItem.classList.add("!z-0")
      owlItem.firstChild.classList.remove(
        "origin-[left_center]",
        "origin-[right_center]",
        "origin-center",
      )
      if (owlItem?.classList.contains("active")) {
        if (owlItemActiveCounter === 1) {
          owlItem.firstChild.classList.add("origin-[left_center]")
        } else if (
          owlItemActiveCounter === getOwlcarouselResponsiveMaxItems(event)
        ) {
          owlItem.firstChild.classList.add("origin-[right_center]")
        } else {
          owlItem.firstChild.classList.add("origin-center")
        }
        owlItemActiveCounter++
      }
    })
  }

  const applyOwlStyles = (event) => {
    const owlCarousel = event.target
    const owlItems = owlCarousel.querySelectorAll(".owl-item")

    owlCarousel.classList.add("relative")
    owlCarousel
      .querySelector(".owl-stage-outer")
      ?.classList.add("!overflow-visible", "!overflow-x-clip")

    owlItems.forEach((owlItem, index) => {
      owlItem.addEventListener("mouseover", addHoverClasses, false)
      owlItem.addEventListener("mouseout", removeHoverClasses, false)
    })

    const owldotsContainer = owlCarousel.querySelector(".owl-dots")
    owldotsContainer?.classList.add(
      "absolute",
      "!-top-4",
      "right-0",
      "-translate-y-full",
      "!flex",
      "!gap-2",
      "!items-center",
    )

    const owldots = owldotsContainer?.querySelectorAll(".owl-dot") ?? []
    owldots.forEach((olwDot) => {
      const span = olwDot.querySelector("span")
      span.classList.add("!m-0", "!rounded-none", "!w-4", "!h-1")
      span.classList.remove("!bg-primary-600")
      if (olwDot.classList.contains("active")) {
        span.classList.add("!bg-primary-600")
      }
    })

    const owlNav = owlCarousel?.querySelector(".owl-nav")
    owlNav?.classList.add("!m-0", "!top-0", "!bottom-0", "!w-full")

    const owlPrev = owlNav?.querySelector(".owl-prev")
    const owlNext = owlNav?.querySelector(".owl-next")

    owlPrev?.classList.add(
      "!absolute",
      "!h-full",
      "!m-0",
      "!bg-black",
      "!bg-opacity-60",
      "!text-white",
      "!text-6xl",
      "!font-opensans",
      "!left-0",
      "!w-[40px]",
      "!rounded-none",
      "!rounded-r-md",
      "-translate-y-full",
    )
    owlNext?.classList.add(
      "!absolute",
      "!h-full",
      "!m-0",
      "!bg-black",
      "!bg-opacity-60",
      "!text-white",
      "!text-6xl",
      "!font-opensans",
      "!right-0",
      "!w-[40px]",
      "!rounded-none",
      "!rounded-l-md",
      "-translate-y-full",
    )

    owlPrev?.querySelector("span").classList.add("align-super")
    owlNext?.querySelector("span").classList.add("align-super")
  }

  jQuery(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    stagePadding: 50,
    nav: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1,
      },
      600: {
        items: 3,
      },
      1000: {
        items: 5,
      },
    },
    onInitialized: (event) => {
      applyOwlStyles(event)
      applyTransformOrigin(event)
      resizeContainer(event)
    },
    onTranslated: (event) => {
      applyTransformOrigin(event)
    },
    onResized: (event) => {
      applyOwlStyles(event)
      applyTransformOrigin(event)
      resizeContainer(event)
    },
  })


  function resizeContainer(event) {
    const owlCarousel = event.target
    repeat5x(() => {
      const height = owlCarousel.querySelector(".owl-item").clientHeight
      if (height > 10) {
        htmlElement.style.setProperty("--owl-carousel-height", `${height}px`)
      }
    })
  }

  function repeat5x(fn) {
    setTimeout(fn, 0)
    setTimeout(fn, 100)
    setTimeout(fn, 333)
    setTimeout(fn, 666)
    setTimeout(fn, 2500)
  }
}
.owl-carousel-container {
  height: var(--owl-carousel-height) !important;
  max-height: var(--owl-carousel-height) !important;
}

.owl-prev, .owl-next {
 height: var(--owl-carousel-height) !important;
 max-height: var(--owl-carousel-height) !important;
 top: var(--owl-carousel-height) !important;
}

.owl-carousel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.owl-stage:hover:after {
  height: var(--owl-carousel-height) !important;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<p>another element</p>
<p>another element</p>
<p>another element</p>
<section class="mx-auto w-screen relative flex flex-col gap-4 px-5">
    <div class="owl-carousel-container">
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
          <div class="item group transition-all hover:absolute hover:scale-125 border border-red-600">
              <div href="#" class="card bg-neutral-900 rounded-md cursor-pointer overflow-hidden">
                  <div>
                      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKSRTtOrtjLaagEC2gTK6VsPq4NEFk_72hhg&s"
                          alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="hidden group-hover:flex bg-white p-1.5 flex-col h-fit w-full">
                      <div class="flex gap-3 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                          <span class="">
                              MOVIE TITLE
                          </span>
                      </div>
                      <a href="" class="text-red-600 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                          try to click me you can't
                      </a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item group transition-all hover:absolute hover:scale-125 border border-red-600 overflow-hidden">
              <div href="#" class="card bg-neutral-900 rounded-md cursor-pointer overflow-hidden">
                  <div>
                      <img src="https://occ-0-6613-7435.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v6/Qs00mKCpRvrkl3HZAN5KwEL1kpE/AAAABQquP3MObc4Xmx8fS1E0EtFypAJFcNs8U73s6OHL2GjPOuIRbKkknfytMjCRkky6eDIe_8LHwBndef1-gQiN3IMX5NEqFRShrIi9MKSOMGvoTalZ2GRya1eswfUOXrTJ6Nnflg.webp?r=bb3"
                          alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="hidden group-hover:flex bg-white p-1.5 flex-col h-fit w-full">
                      <div class="flex gap-3 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                          <span class="">
                              MOVIE TITLE
                          </span>
                      </div>
                      <a href="" class="text-red-600 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                          try to click me you can't
                      </a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item group transition-all hover:absolute hover:scale-125 border border-red-600">
              <div href="#" class="card bg-neutral-900 rounded-md cursor-pointer overflow-hidden">
                  <div>
                      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKSRTtOrtjLaagEC2gTK6VsPq4NEFk_72hhg&s"
                          alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="hidden group-hover:flex bg-white p-1.5 flex-col h-fit w-full">
                      <div class="flex gap-3 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                          <span class="">
                              MOVIE TITLE
                          </span>
                      </div>
                      <a href="" class="text-red-600 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                          try to click me you can't
                      </a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item group transition-all hover:absolute hover:scale-125 border border-red-600">
              <div href="#" class="card bg-neutral-900 rounded-md cursor-pointer overflow-hidden">
                  <div>
                      <img src="https://placecats.com/340/192" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="hidden group-hover:flex bg-white p-1.5 flex-col h-fit w-full">
                      <div class="flex gap-3 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                          <span class="">
                              MOVIE TITLE
                          </span>
                      </div>
                      <a href="" class="text-red-600 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                          try to click me you can't
                      </a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item group transition-all hover:absolute hover:scale-125 border border-red-600">
              <div href="#" class="card bg-neutral-900 rounded-md cursor-pointer overflow-hidden">
                  <div>
                      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKSRTtOrtjLaagEC2gTK6VsPq4NEFk_72hhg&s"
                          alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="hidden group-hover:flex bg-white p-1.5 flex-col h-fit w-full">
                      <div class="flex gap-3 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                          <span class="">
                              MOVIE TITLE
                          </span>
                      </div>
                      <a href="" class="text-red-600 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                          try to click me you can't
                      </a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item group transition-all hover:absolute hover:scale-125 border border-red-600">
              <div href="#" class="card bg-neutral-900 rounded-md cursor-pointer overflow-hidden">
                  <div>
                      <img src="https://occ-0-6613-7435.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v6/Qs00mKCpRvrkl3HZAN5KwEL1kpE/AAAABQquP3MObc4Xmx8fS1E0EtFypAJFcNs8U73s6OHL2GjPOuIRbKkknfytMjCRkky6eDIe_8LHwBndef1-gQiN3IMX5NEqFRShrIi9MKSOMGvoTalZ2GRya1eswfUOXrTJ6Nnflg.webp?r=bb3"
                          alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="hidden group-hover:flex bg-white p-1.5 flex-col h-fit w-full">
                      <div class="flex gap-3 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                          <span class="">
                              MOVIE TITLE
                          </span>
                      </div>
                      <a href="" class="text-red-600 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                          try to click me you can't
                      </a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item group transition-all hover:absolute hover:scale-125 border border-red-600">
              <div href="#" class="card bg-neutral-900 rounded-md cursor-pointer overflow-hidden">
                  <div>
                      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKSRTtOrtjLaagEC2gTK6VsPq4NEFk_72hhg&s"
                          alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="hidden group-hover:flex bg-white p-1.5 flex-col h-fit w-full">
                      <div class="flex gap-3 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                          <span class="">
                              MOVIE TITLE
                          </span>
                      </div>
                      <a href="" class="text-red-600 sm:group-hover:scale-[.8] origin-top-left w-[calc(100%/0.8)]">
                          try to click me you can't
                      </a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
<p>another element</p>
<p>another element</p>
<p>another element</p>




Wow awesome, thanks. Just I do not understand the random value applied in resizeContainer height > 10 ?

@akio In some tests, I received values of 2px, I believe this happens before or during the carousel be created. If there were no conditional, the global variable could be updated with the value of 2px, which would quickly result in an error where it gets too small and restores (it would look like a glitch).
